# Radio button en item y SQlite

Tags: android, json

Estoy tratando de replantear una pregunta anterior que está muy confusa.

En primer lugar, teniendo en cuenta que en la base de datos local hay una serie de datos que han sido insertados previamente, genero una consulta y despliego el resultado de dicha consulta en un ListView. Cada Item del ListView contiene un `RadioButton` que está desmarcado por defecto.

La idea es que cuando le den click al control radio del item respectivo, se actualice un dato correspondiente al registro de dicho item.

Tengo las siguientes clases:

DatabaseHelper. java

```
 public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "GCM";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "newsTable";
public static final String IDs = "_id";
public static final String MSG = "MESSAGE";
public static final String FIRMA = "firma";


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + IDs + " INTEGER    PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + MSG + " STRING, " + FIRMA + " STRING)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

la clase que controla la base de datos

```
  public class SQLController {

private DatabaseHelper DatabaseHelper;
private Context ourcontext;
private SQLiteDatabase database;

public SQLController(Context c) {
    ourcontext = c;
}

public SQLController open() throws SQLException {
    DatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(ourcontext);
    database = DatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;

}

public void close() {
    DatabaseHelper.close();
}


//Getting Cursor to read data from table
public Cursor readData() {
    String[] allColumns = new String[] { DatabaseHelper.IDs, DatabaseHelper.MSG };
    Cursor c = database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, allColumns, null,
            null, null, null, DatabaseHelper.IDs+" DESC",null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
 }


 }
```

y dentro del bundle en MainActivity el cursor que muestra la consulta en el listview

```
     FIRMA = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.firma);
 //////TRASMO SQLITE QUE CONSULTA Y MUESTRA EN UN LIST VIEW /////
    dbcon = new SQLController(this);
    dbcon.open();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

      Cursor cursor = dbcon.readData();
     String[] from = new String[] { DatabaseHelper.IDs,  DatabaseHelper.MSG};
     int[] to = new int[] { R.id.ids, R.id.msg};


     SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, cursor, from, to);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Fuera del bundle en la clase Main Activity esta el metodo del radiobutton, pero nose como llamar correctamente al método en la clase  SQLcontroller

```
   public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
      boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
    String id = DatabaseHelper.IDs.toString();
    String firma = "ok";

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.firma:
            if (checked)



                dbcon.open();
            SQLController db = new SQLController(this);

            db.actualizar(String id, String firma);
            // notifies user

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FIRMA CORRECTS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Pirates are the best
                break;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar, para operar sobre la base de datos local necesitas un objeto de tipo `SQLiteDatabase`. A continuación, para realizar una operación de actualización, necesitas construir un objeto de tipo ContentValues en el que introduzcas los datos que quieres actualizar y, finalmente, utilizas el metodo `update` que te proporciona el objeto de tipo `SQLiteDatabase` (db):

```
public int actualizar(int id, String firma){
  ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
  contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.FIRMA, firma);
  return db.update(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, contentValues, DatabaseHelper.IDs + " = " + id, null);
}
```

De modo que simplemente hay que agregar el método actualizar en tu clase SQLController.

- Nota: Debes ir con cuidado de no nombrar tus variables exactamente igual que tus clases. Esto es erróneo `private DatabaseHelper DatabaseHelper;`, dicha variable la debes nombrar de otro modo, por ejemplo `databaseHelper`.

Dicho esto, la clase SQLController quedaría del siguiente modo:

```
public class SQLController {

    //Debes ir con cuidado de no nombrar la variable igual que la clase
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper; 
    private Context ourcontext;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    public SQLController(Context c) {
        ourcontext = c;
    }

    public SQLController open() throws SQLException {
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(ourcontext);
        database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public int actualizar(int id, String firma){
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.FIRMA, firma);
        return databaseHelper.update(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, contentValues, DatabaseHelper.IDs + " = " + id, null);
    }

    public void close() {
        databaseHelper.close();
    }

    //Getting Cursor to read data from table
    public Cursor readData() {
        String[] allColumns = new String[] { DatabaseHelper.IDs, DatabaseHelper.MSG };
        Cursor c = database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, allColumns, null, null, null, null, DatabaseHelper.IDs+" DESC",null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: gracias por contestar, no se como llamar al método del SQL controller desde el main a traves del public void RadioButtonClicked , trate usar ExampleObject obj = new ExampleObject(); pero me pide parámetros y no se como hacerlo

Comment: Le anexo arriba la forma como lo estoy llamando, pero me da error

Comment: ¿Puedes adjuntar la traza del error?